# What is the difference between .NET Framework and .NET Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core

**What is the difference between .Net Framework and .Net Core ?**

This question was asked by interviewer and I didn't make it!

**He also asked :**

> Why is it called .Net Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is a the difference between .NET Core and .NET Framework

***.NET Framework:***

The ***.NET framework*** is a software development framework from Microsoft. It provides a controlled programming environment where software can be developed, installed and executed on Windows-based operating systems.

**.NET Core:**

***.NET Core*** is an open-source, general-purpose development platform maintained by Microsoft and the .NET community on GitHub. It's cross-platform (supporting Windows, macOS, and Linux) and can be used to build device, cloud, and IoT applications.

***[source]***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/

https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3734/net-framework-net

Answer (score 4):

To put it simple .NET Core is the new cross-platform and fully open source version of .NET (.NET Framework isn't cross-platform nor is it open source)

Comment: *Core* means Cross-Platform Support?

Comment: I don't think it necessarily has any meaning.. it's just a name like Java, Python, Django doesn't have to mean anything @RaviMakwana .. please mark the answer if it helped you

Comment: How is that, .NET Framework is non-cross-platform non-open-source that is the difference between the two, as stated ? @Stefan

Comment: Upvoted because it does answer one of the questions, and the comment answers another about naming. Name is opinion based because Microsoft have released nothing official (to my knowledge) as to why it's named as such, but one could argue that it's "Core" because it may represent the fact that the framework contains only the Core components required to run cross-platform and nothing that tightly couples it to Windows.

Comment: @Stefan Answer edited

Comment: @ColinM I agree, however I couldn't find any official source stating that this is the reason for the naming, so we can only take a wild guess

Comment: @SmailGalijasevic This answer is useful but for interviewer point of view.. he wants more... like example "what we can do or not"

Comment: @RaviMakwana we can do cross-platform ^^ basically enables you to use cheaper linux infrastructures for production and develop on linux/mac.. there are of course other differences but going into detail and implementation differences you could talk days

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful links for you to read:

https://dzone.com/articles/net-framework-vs-net-core
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/difference-between-net-framework-and-net-core/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

Comment: Those articles are really informative, Thanks